# SqlDataReader returns x rows but SQL query returns y rows

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

First time post as I'm a bit stuck here.

I am using this code to return some rows from a SQL Server database:

```
public static SqlDataReader SQLSelect(string sqlcommand, string[,] parameters, int length)
{
    try
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcommand, conn);

        var allLength = parameters.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length - length; i++)
        {
            string paramid = parameters[i, 0];

            if (paramid == "@date" || paramid == "@Date" || paramid == "@DATE")
            {
                string paramvalue = parameters[i, 1];
                DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(paramvalue);
                paramvalue = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(paramid, paramvalue));
            }
            else
            {
                string paramvalue = parameters[i, 1];
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(paramid, paramvalue));
            }
        }

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        return reader;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This function is called like so

```
string[,] parameters = new string[1, 2] { { "@studentid", studentid } };
SqlDataReader reader = Common.SQLSelect(Common.tblstudentprogressselectforprinting, parameters, 1);
```

now all runs fine except the reader only contains 13 rows of data where as the actual query being

```
exec sp_tblstudentprogress_selectforprinting @studentid=N'87'
```

as an example, returns 91 rows.

I'm at a loss as to why this is the case. Only thing I have noticed is when using SQL Server profiler, running the query from SQL Server, there is a RPC: Started and Completed, as for running from withing my web app, there is only an RPC: Started.

Any thoughts on this?

EDIT:

here is how I enumerate the reader

```
        protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[,] parameters = new string[1, 2] { { "@studentid", studentid } };
            SqlDataReader reader = Common.SQLSelect(Common.tblstudentprogressselectforprinting, parameters, 1);

            string firstname = txtFirstName.Text;
            string lastname = txtLastName.Text;
            int i=0;
            string[] heading1 = new string[reader.FieldCount];
            string[] heading2 = new string[reader.FieldCount];
            string[] log = new string[reader.FieldCount];

            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    heading1[i] = "Progress Log for: Block: " + reader["block"].ToString() + " Lesson: " + reader["lesson"].ToString();
                    heading2[i] = "";
                    log[i] =
                        /*"PROGRESS LOG for " + reader["firstname"].ToString() + " " + reader["lastname"].ToString() + " Printed on " + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + Environment.NewLine +*/
                        Environment.NewLine +
                        "Teacher: " + reader["teacher"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Date: " + reader["date"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Year: " + reader["year"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Block: " + reader["block"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Lesson: " + reader["lesson"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Warm Up: " + reader["warmup"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Range: " + reader["range"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Technique Sheet: " + reader["techniquesheet"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Technique Other: " + reader["techniqueother"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        Environment.NewLine +
                        "Notes: " + reader["notes"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        Environment.NewLine +
                        "Mark: " + reader["mark"].ToString()+ Environment.NewLine ;

                    i++;
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                if (Common.conn != null)
                {
                    Common.conn.Close();
                }
            }


            Common.PDFCreateProgressLog("Progress log for: " + firstname + " " + lastname, "Progress log for: " + firstname + " " + lastname, "PDF_" + firstname + " " + lastname + "-" + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".pdf", "Progress log for: " + firstname + " " + lastname, log, heading1, heading2);

        }
```

Comment: You're unfortunately not showing us what you **do** with the `SqlDataReader` that is returned - how are you enumerating over all the rows it returns??

Comment: If you are planning on returning the reader and not passing in a already open connection you ***really*** should be doing `reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);` so when the reader gets disposed (you are disposing the returned reader, right?) it will close the connection too.

Comment: Such differences are often due to different ANSI settings.  For example, ANSI_NULLS is OFF by default when using ADO.NET, and ON by default when using SQL Server Management Studio.  I suggest you try playing with the settings in Management Studio until you get consistent behaviour.  Then, if possible, update your SP so it doesn't depend on the ANSI settings.

Comment: The missing RPC:Completed is an important clue. I don't think you are fully draining the reader. The bug is elsewhere. +1 for detective work.

Comment: @marc_s you don't need to know how I enumerate over the rows as the reader.fieldcount returns 13 and not 91.But here is the code that enumerates the reader in the edited post

Comment: @Scottchamberlain Please see extra code added, if I passed a closed connection, I was not able to read the reader, I had tried this previously hence why I came up with this solution in the end.

Comment: @Joe All my Stored Procs have
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

have tried it with off and still same results.

Comment: @usr thanks, but I don't understand why, im under the assumption if I call a SP, it should return the same data, unless the code is moving on to quick or something.

Comment: Also, I urge you to get rid of those try/catch blocks. You are hiding from yourself the information you may need to solve the problem: the exceptions you may be getting will be consumed by the catch blocks and you'll never know about them.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I know this, but it never goes into the catch in this instance, im still developing a error logging mechanisim so will have code in there later. but for this situation that will not matter

Comment: Don't use try/catch in that manner for logging, not if you think you need try/catch around everything. Ask yourself: what happens if there's no try/catch blocks at all. When you find that you need to add one in order to ensure logging, that's the time to add one.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the meaning of the `FieldCount` property.  It identifies the number of *Columns*, not the number of *Rows*.  You cannot determine the total number of rows from a streaming source like a Reader, without enumerating all of the rows first (at least once, anyway).

So you will need to extend your arrays each time (lists might be easier for this) you read a row from the Reader and test the Reader to se when there are no more rows.